# Style first table row of group identified by td classname sibling to another row

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow

How can I do to change the style of the first row of a group of rows (identified by a td with a sub-item class) that is near to a sibling row (identified by a td with the item class):

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item"><!-- I need to style this one --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item"><!-- I need to style this one --></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like to style with an inset box-shadow all the first rows matched by this criteria.

I tried with the sibling operator without success:

CSS:

```css
tr > td.item ~ tr > td.sub-item:first {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current code you would have to use `:nth-[last]-child()`

```css
tr:first-child + tr .sub-item, tr:nth-last-child(2) + tr .sub-item {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">2<!-- I need to style this one --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">6<!-- I need to style this one --></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Also, you can add a class to `tr` and achieve what you want.

```css
.row + tr .sub-item {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="item">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">2<!-- I need to style this one --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="item">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sub-item">6<!-- I need to style this one --></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 - however to complete the anwser, if the intention is to just change the first row, you also could use `:first-child`

Comment: Great, it works fine! The code is dinamically created by fullcalendar library, but I listen the creation process in order to add the .row class and then evaluate your CSS expression. I finally use the second one option .row + tr .sub-item